# Stacking mobs on players in vanilla minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there anyway to stack the player on mobs? I already know how to stack mobs on other mobs, like this:

```
/summon <entity> {Riding:{<entity>}}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how I can do something like this to stack mobs on the player. Is there anyway I can do this in **vanilla** minecraft? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Also who agrees with me that minecraft's command syntax sorta "feels good" to write?

Comment: Minecarts and boats can ride other entities, which can be riden by players.  Don't know of any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube:

You can do this using NBT Explorer or mods or plugins
Commands? No

Comment: Also, could you provide the link for the video? Sometimes the video won't load on my crappy iphone.